# Navbar and Slide inside Header in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to make to my header content be a slide and when I scroll down the galery is hide and my navbar is top now like the gif.
I need something to start the idea, I  appreciate your help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-shrinking-header-for-segments-in-ionic/) by Josh Morony should get you started! Have fun implementing!

Comment: Thanks namesake!! This is perfect

Comment: No problem, always happy to help!

Comment: Good answers do more than simply reference an external site and suggest that the OP refer to it. Answers that primarily reference an external site should include a summary of the information so that it becomes a primary source as well as a reference ([more info...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers))

Answer (score 2):

```
I hope this will help you.

<header>
  <div class="header-banner">
</div>

<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">$4,456-5,778 your text</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<section class="content">
  <p>Here add huge dummy content to check scroll position.</p>
</section>



 header {
 height:360px;
 }
.header-banner {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 }
 .fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  width: 100%; 
  }
   nav {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background: #292f36;
  postion:fixed;
  z-index:10;
  }
  nav ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left:0;
  text-align:right;
  width: 960px; 
  max-width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #a9abae;
  }


  $(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {
   $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
}
else {
   $('nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
}
});
```